# Tweepy: problem retrieving username informations with twitter v2 api

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a problem migrating from the tweepy API for the twitter v1.1 API to the tweepy Client for the twitter v2 API. I'm trying to fetch a query of tweets and store them in a dataframe and then in a csv file for later analysis. I use something like:

```
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for tweet in tw.Paginator(
    client.search_recent_tweets, 
    query,
    expansions=['author_id'],
    tweet_fields=["public_metrics"],
    user_fields=['username'],
    max_results=100).flatten(limit=10):
    tweet.data['retweet_count'] = tweet.data['public_metrics']['retweet_count']
    df = df.append(tweet.data,ignore_index=True)
```

I can correctly fetch the retweet_count number and add it to the dataframe but i cannot access the "username" from the user_fields.

Any help is appreciated. Maybe i'm just i newbie but i can assure you i've searched all the day a solution!

EDIT:

Turns out that the answer is actually in the documentation! :) The problem is the "flatten" method that discards the "includes" attribute that's where the data i stored. I've modified the code as follows:

```
query = '#scienza -is:retweet lang:it'
df = pd.DataFrame()

for tweet_batch in tw.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
    query, expansions=['author_id'],tweet_fields=["public_metrics"],user_fields=['username'],max_results=100):
    data = tweet_batch.data
    users = tweet_batch.includes['users']
    print(len(data),len(users))
    users_df = pd.DataFrame(users)
    users_df.columns = ['author_id','author_name','author_username']
    tweet_batch_df = pd.concat([users_df, pd.DataFrame(data)], axis=1)
    df = df.append(tweet_batch_df,ignore_index=True)
```

Now my problem is this: the data and the users list have different lengths, so it turns out that i cannot retrieve the username for all tweets! The output for the "print" statement is:

```
100 82
100 81
56 44
```

I checked a tweet whose author is missing and i think it's a regular tweet with the hashtag "#scienza" in it. I can fix the code using a "merge" statement instead of the "concat" but still i'll get nearly 20% of NaNs in the username column.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? Also, after removing the `flatten` method, did you get the tweets' public_metrics in the Response object? It's not showing anymore, just doesn't exist as an attribute. Same parameters used.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it happens beacuase there are multiple articles from the same author. Using merge on "author_id" instead of concat solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).